# SameTime with Different TImeZone

Tags: java

Why does the program printout the same output/time with different `TimeZone`?

```
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone timeZone_1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Rangoon");
    cal.setTimeZone(timeZone_1);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());

    TimeZone timeZone_2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo");
    cal.setTimeZone(timeZone_2);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Example Output :

```
Thu Nov 22 09:00:33 MMT 2012
Thu Nov 22 09:00:33 MMT 2012
```

My Expected Output is:

```
Thu Nov 22 09:00:33 MMT 2012
Thu Nov 22 11:30:33 MMT 2012
```

Comment: You ask about "same output/time" while the "Example Output" displayed a 2h30m difference...

Comment: Date objects are your system dependent. Try getting a string out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine, it's only the debug output that's wrong (misleading). [`cal.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) returns [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, which is independent from time zone. But [`Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) always prints this date with systems' time zone. `Date.toString()` is so counterintuitive (it displays calendar time with system time zone while it barely stores number of millliseconds) that it should have been banned/deprecated.

To have accurate logging use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or call various `Calendar.get*()` methods instead:

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

And as always with any questions regarding Java date/time handling, consider [jodatime](/questions/tagged/jodatime)...

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```java
Instant                                           // Represent a moment as seen in UTC, that is, with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
.now()                                            // Capture the current moment in UTC.
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Rangoon" ) )            // Adjust from UTC to a particular time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock/calendar.
.atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )   // Adjust from one time zone to another. Same moment, different wall-clock/calendar. 
.toString()                                       // Generate text in ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of time zone in square brackets.
```

### `java.util.Date#toString` tells a lie

[The Answer by Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508242/642706) is correct. Your call to `cal.getTime()` returns a `java.util.Date` object whose `toString` method lies to you. That `Date#toString` method has the anti-feature of dynamically applying a current default time zone to its value which is actually stored as a moment seen in UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

This anti-feature is one of many reasons to avoid `Date` & `Calendar` classes.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

#### `ZonedDateTime`

To represent the current moment, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

You can adjust that moment to be seen through a particular time zone. Apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to produce a [`ZonedDateTime][2]` object.

```
ZoneId zRangoon = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Rangoon" );
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;

Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Always in UTC (offset of zero). 

// Adjust that moment into particular time zones.
ZonedDateTime zdtRangoon = instant.atZone( zRangoon ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = instant.atZone( zTokyo ) ;
```

The objects referenced by variables `instant`, `zdtRangoon`, and `zdtTokyo` all represent the very same moment, the same point on the timeline — three views, one moment.

Call `ZonedDateTime#toString` to generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format wisely extended to append the name of time zone in square brackets.

```
String outputRangoon = zdtRangoon.toString() ;
String outputTokyo = zdtTokyo.toString() ;
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/O1PfRu). Notice the difference in date as well as time-of-day.

```
instant.toString() = 2023-12-31T20:36:15.449185Z
outputRangoon = 2024-01-01T03:06:15.449185+06:30[Asia/Rangoon]
outputTokyo = 2024-01-01T05:36:15.449185+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
```

To get localized output, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow to find more info.